# Task cancelling for an autocomplete field doesn't cancel all previous tasks

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a search method that returns search suggestions to the UI.  This method is fired every time the user enters a new character into the search box.

I have added some cancellation code to cancel the previous search request. This works but not all the time.

```
private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

private async Task UserSearch(string searchCriteria)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Searching for {0}....", searchCriteria);

    try
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        this.Suggestions = await this.SearchAsync(searchCriteria, cts.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Search({0}) cancelled", searchCriteria);
    }
}

private async Task<IList<string>> SearchAsync(string searchCriteria, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    CancellationTokenSource previousCts = this.cancellationTokenSource;
    CancellationTokenSource linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancelToken);

    this.cancellationTokenSource = linkedCts;

    // if previous task running cancel it
    if (previousCts != null)
    {
        previousCts.Cancel();
    }

    linkedCts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    List<string> results =
        (await this.searchProvider.SearchAsync(searchCriteria, linkedCts.Token)).ToList();

    Debug.WriteLine("Search({0}) returned {1} records", searchCriteria, results.Count);

    linkedCts.Dispose();
    this.cancellationTokenSource = null;

    return results;
}
```

For example.  I get the following debug messages:

```
SearchTerm changing to: Di 
Searching for Di....
SearchTerm changing to: Dia
Searching for Dia....
Search(Di) cancelled
SearchTerm changing to: Diap
Searching for Diap....
Search(Diap) returned 323 records
Search(Dia) returned 3230 records
```

As you can see the first search gets cancelled but the second one doesn't and it gets returned after the last search giving incorrect results to the user.

How can I ensure previous tasks are always cancelled?

Comment: What does SearchAsync do? Does it actually respond to cancellation?

Comment: @usr It essentially passes it through to SQLite.Net `QueryAsync` method https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/master/src/SQLite.Net.Async/SQLiteAsyncConnection.cs#L532

Comment: If you already executed the query prior to cancellation, and the lowest API called isn't listening to that token while querying, you're not going to get canceled.

Comment: Thanks @YuvalItzchakov adding an extra `token.ThowIfCancellationRequested()` to the bottom of the `this.SearchProvider.SearchAsync()` method seems to do the trick.  Is there any rules as to how often to add this check?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably complicating your solution a little. All you need to do is see if there is an existing operation in progress that hasn't been cancelled and cancel it. Then perform the new search. Untested, but I think this should do it.

```
private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

private async Task UserSearch(string searchCriteria)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Searching for {0}....", searchCriteria);

    try
    {       
        if(cancellationTokenSource != null && 
           !cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }

        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        this.Suggestions = await this.searchProvider.SearchAsync(searchCriteria, linkedCts.Token);

        Debug.WriteLine("Search({0}) returned {1} records", searchCriteria, results.Count);

    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Search({0}) cancelled", searchCriteria);
    }
}
```

Comment: The fix was to add an extra `token.ThowIfCancellationRequested()` to the `this.SearchProvider.SearchAsync()` method.  But I have tidied up my code based on your simplified version.

Answer (score 0):

You cancel your previous query too late, query it as soon as you are able (directly after receiving user input, not inside the next query).

Comment: I've tried your suggest and still get the same results as in the question

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is multithread access to *this.cancellationTokenSource*. If say thread 2 cancels thread 1 too late (*searchProvider.SearchAsync* is completed) this.cancellationTokenSource can be cleared after assignment (i.e. thread 2 executes *this.cancellationTokenSource = linkedCts;* and thread 1 after that calls *this.cancellationTokenSource = null;*). This will effectively disable cancelling of thread 2 completely

Thus you'd better have one search cancelled before the next one starts like in the suggestion from @Ned Stoyanov